# Equation of the line, which parallel to $x+2y+7=0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> Find an equation of the line that is tangent to the graph of $f(x)=(x-1)^{-1/2}$ and parallel to the line $x+2y+7=0$.

I find $x= -1$ from $\sqrt{x-1}=\sqrt{x}-i$

The answer is $2y+7=-1$?

Comment: How can you find $\;x\;$ *only* from $\;f(x)\;$ ?

Comment: f(x)=0=(x-1)^(-1/2)?

Comment: No, why? Why would finding out what $\;f(0)\;$ is help you in this case??

Comment: You've tagged your question certainly wrong.

Comment: sorry,someone edited it i know the tag should be differentiation and application..?

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$f'(x)=-\frac12(x-1)^{-3/2}\stackrel ?=-\frac12\iff (x-1)^{-3/2}=1\iff x=2$$

So you want a line with slope $\;-\frac12\;$ and through the point $\;(2,f(2))\;$

Comment: why (x−1)^(−3/2)=1?

Comment: @user113477, that's the rule: $$\left((x-a)^n\right)'=n(x-a)^{n-1}\;,\;\;\forall\,n\neq-1$$